How to remove child lookup which is populated on parent when the associated child is deleted
On the account object we have a contact lookup field
We have multiple contacts as a related list on accounts right
When we delete the contact record/ update the account on contact record, if it's associated with the respective account then we have to remove the contact lookup on account
Example: we have account1 record having con2 which is lookup on account is populated.
And the Account1 having con1,con2,con3 etc.. contacts in the related list.when we delete the con2 record / update with another account which is different we have to remove the contact lookup Respective account .
Suggest the solution.

What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to add that information.

Your question is not clear.  Are you saying that when the contact is deleted, you want to replace it in contact lookup field with another random contact in the account?  You need to explain more and include the work you have already done.

If I understand correctly, this works out-of-the-box. And the answer below is kind of surreal, because it's overlooking this, being generated by AI?!?!

@FelixvanHove I think the wrinkle here is the extra lookup field on Account. Having that field doesn't make sense to me (sounds like maybe OP should enable "Allow Contacts" to be related to multiple Accounts to get the AccountContactRelationship object), but I'm sure that plenty of the stuff my employer has told me to do wouldn't make sense to others.

I agree I might not (and still don't) understand it correctly, but nevermind:-)

Please refer the answer given by vikas.Thanks!

Here's how you can implement it:
Create an Apex Trigger on the Contact Object:
The trigger will be fired after a contact record is deleted or updated. It will update the account record to remove the lookup reference if necessary.
Trigger Code:
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after delete, after update) {
Set<Id> accountIdsToUpdate = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id, Id> accountToContactMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

if (Trigger.isDelete) {
    for (Contact contact : Trigger.old) {
        if (contact.AccountId != null) {
            accountIdsToUpdate.add(contact.AccountId);
            accountToContactMap.put(contact.AccountId, contact.Id);
        }
    }
}

if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    for (Contact contact : Trigger.old) {
        if (contact.AccountId != Trigger.newMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId) {
            accountIdsToUpdate.add(contact.AccountId);
            accountToContactMap.put(contact.AccountId, contact.Id);
        }
    }
}

if (!accountIdsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Contact_Lookup__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIdsToUpdate];

    for (Account account : accountsToUpdate) {
        if (accountToContactMap.containsKey(account.Id) && account.Contact_Lookup__c == accountToContactMap.get(account.Id)) {
            account.Contact_Lookup__c = null;
        }
    }

    if (!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
}

}
Explanation:
Trigger Definition: The trigger is defined on the Contact object and is set to fire after delete and after update.
Collect Account IDs: The trigger collects the IDs of the accounts that need to be updated. For deleted contacts, it collects the account IDs from Trigger.old. For updated contacts, it checks if the AccountId has changed and collects the old account IDs.
Fetch Account Records: A SOQL query is used to fetch the account records that need to be updated. The WHERE Id IN :accountIdsToUpdate clause ensures that only the relevant account records are fetched.
Clear Contact Lookup: The trigger iterates through the fetched account records and sets the contact lookup field (Contact_Lookup__c in this example) to null if it matches the deleted or updated contact ID.
Update Account Records: The account records are updated in the database.

Thank you so much Vikash.Its working as expected.

Hi Vikash, and welcome to SFSE! If you haven't already, please take a moment to read about [answer] and take our quick [tour]. Please be advised that we actively discourage the use of ChatGPT/LLVM/etc. If you did not use an AI, please consider making an [edit] to make this post sound less like an AI. If you did, please be advised that posts that using AI is not permitted, and this answer may be subject to deletion.
